Why is it so hard to rename tabs in gnome terminal?
Ubuntu 22.04. Two part question. Years ago, I was able to right-click on a terminal and set the title. I cannot do that now. I vaguely remember a technical discussion of the option doesn't exist. First question is why was a user-friendly mechanism to set the title never created based on the new implementation?
Second question is how can I actually change the title? I've followed tutorials to comment out case statements in ~/.bashrc, run gnome-terminal --title, and echoed ANSI escape characters to the terminals. None of it changes the title of the tab or window.

The first (and the title) question is probably off topic. We the users can't answer that in any objective way. Questions seeking opinions are off topic here. Bug reports and feature requests are also off topic here. If the "why" question is a rant, then again... you guessed it. So, the bottom line is, you may only ask the "how" and not the why I'm this Q&A site.

The only way to change the title runtime is via corresponding escape sequences, such as printf '\e]0;newtitle\e\\'. If that seemingly doesn't work then that's because your shell prompt overwrites that; modify your shell prompt not to tamper with the title if that's what you want. (Append ; sleep 10 to the previous command to prove that this is what's indeed happening.)

If you want to easily change a tab name, just open and use a different terminal that behaves as you want. There are some features gnome-terminal provides easily (just as different tabs using different font/sizes & window resizing automatically when you flip tabs) that aren't as easy as other windows, but what we expect from our terminals vary, so use the terminal that suits your needs (my normal behavior has two different terminals open as that helps me work better in being able to find the correct one quickly)

This question is similar to: How to change the title of the current terminal tab using only the command line. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
